# C create many child process using exec and pipe

Tags: c, linux, pipe, exec, fork

I want to create as many child processes as the user sends in the argument. And I succeeded. However, I have to create child processes using the `exec` function, I do not know how to do it. Childs process are to be created as separate programs and run
by exec. In addition, I would like every child process to communicate with the main process (parent) using `pipe`. I do not know how to do it. So far I managed to write something like this:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>


   int main(int argc, char **argv)
   {
        pid_t pid;

        if(argc < 3)
        {
                printf("Not enought arguments");
                exit(0);
        }

        int number = atoi(argv[2]); // number of childern
        pid_t pids[number],pid_s;
        int i,n=number,status;
        int pipes[number*2];
        char buff[512];

        if(strcmp("-p", argv[1]) == 0)
        {
                //
        }

        if(strcmp("-f", argv[1]) == 0)
        {
                //
        }


        switch (pid = fork()) {
           case -1:
                        perror("Error in fork");
                        exit(0);

                        break;
           case 0:

                   for(i=0; i < n; i++)
                   {
                           if((pids[i] = fork()) < 0)
                           {
                                   perror("error fork");
                           }
                           else if(pids[i] == 0)
                           {
                                close(pipes[0]);
                                char *reply = "message";
                                write(pipes[1], reply, strlen(reply)+1);
                                execvp(argv[0],NULL);
                           }
                   }

                   while(n > 0)
                   {
                           pid_s = wait(&status);
                           --n;
                   }
                          break;
            default:

               close(pipes[1]);
               read(pipes[0],buff,80);
               printf("Message: %s", buff);

                   if(wait(0) == -1)
                   {

                   }

                          break;
         }

        return 0;
}
```

I correct the code, the child creates a new process by the exec. I would like to the child communicated with the main process by pipe. Do it in a loop best?

Comment: The `execve()` family of functions do not create child processes.  For a problem such as yours, you use one of the exec functions after forking, to replace the forked child image with an arbitrary alternative program image.  That is, exec is how you direct a process to run a different program.

Comment: As for piping, a child process inherits all its parent's file descriptors.  You can create a pair of connected, open file descriptors representing the ends of a pipe via the `pipe()` function.  If you do this before forking, then the parent can write to the writing end, and the child can read from the reading end (or vice versa).

Comment: @JohnBollinger what exactly can I use exec after forking?

Comment: Number of pipes = number of child * 2 yes?

Comment: pipes are unidirectional.  Where you want bidirectional communication you need two per child; where you need only unidirectional communication you need only one per child.  Each pipe has two file descriptors associated with it.

Comment: In `else if(pids[i] == 0)` should put `execvp(argv[0], argv)`?

Comment: I don't understand "what exactly can I use exec after forking?". [The `exec(3)` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) describes details of the various POSIX exec functions.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I do not know how to use properly exec to create child process.

Comment: I already told you: the exec functions do not create child processes.  That's what `fork()` does.

Comment: Yes, but in my task is childs process are to be created as separate programs and run by exec. I do not know how to do it.

Comment: exec REPLACES an existing child process, not create/run a child process.  There are lots of examples on stackoverflow.com on how to use the exec() family of functions.  Suggest performing a bit of searching.

Comment: regarding this line: `if(argc < 2)`  the `argc` is count of the number of entries in the `argv[]` array, except for the final NULL entry.  so, with no command line parameters (CMPs)  the value of `argc` will be 1  with one CMPs, the value of `argc` will be 2.  With 2 CMPs (the current scenario) the value of `argc` will be 3, not 2

Comment: the posted code fails to compile.  It causes the compiler to raise several warning and error messages.   Please correct the problems and post an edit (in a new code segment)

Comment: regarding: `         case -1:
                   //              syserr("Error in fork\n");`  the code should not be allowed to fall through into `case 0:`  suggest a `break;` statement before `case 0:`

Comment: the switch() statement contains this 'random'  code, that is not contained in any `case` or `default` code block:  `           if(wait(0) == -1)
                 return 0;`

Comment: A switch() statement should properly expect and handle all cases.  Therefore the posted code switch() statement needs a `default:` case.   Most modern compilers will not crash when none of the `case` statements are 'hit', however, this problem, for good coding practice, needs to be fixed.

Comment: this line: in `case 0:` `pid_t pids[number];` will be re-created each time through some (not in the posted code) loop.  so any saved pid values would be lost.  Suggest moving this line to the beginning of the 'main()` funtion.

Comment: the variable `number` after being declared and set, then is never changed, so why copy it to yet another variable `n` which is also never changed?  The variable `n` just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.

Comment: I correct code, thanks for warnings. Now, I would like to each child process communicate with the main process by pipe.

Comment: you might want to look at the `popen()` function and the `dup2()` function for setting up the two way communication between parent and child.  Suggest starting by just implementing the parent to child part of the communication, then add functionality after getting the one way communication working

Comment: I have to do with the use `pipe`. I wonder how only properly open the pipe for each child.

Comment: this code: `   while(n > 0)
                   {
                           pid_s = wait(&status);
                           --n;
                   }` is in the child execution path,  in general, it should NEVER be executed.

Comment: the code block, beginning with: `for(i=0; i < n; i++)` should be BEFORE the switch() statement and include the switch statement.  However the call to execvp() should remain in the child execution path.  Note: since argv[] is from the main() function signature, this code will continue to re-execute itself forever.  suggest running a different program via the call to `execvp()`

Comment: Can you correct this please?

Comment: I try to send message from child to parent but this not working. I edit code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this example code, snipped from: http://www.cs.ecu.edu/karl/4630/sum01/example1.html  shows how to use the `execvp()` function, with minor modifications by me.

It uses function parsecmd(cmd,argv), which is not writtten here, but which breaks cmd at spaces and stores the pieces into (local array) argv[], followed by a null pointer. For example, parsecmd("eat the banana", argv) will set argv as follows.

```
   argv[0] = "eat"
   argv[1] = "the"
   argv[2] = "banana"
   argv[3] = NULL

This example also presumes that there might be other child processes running in background, and that they might terminate while the shell is waiting for the current command to stop. A function called process_terminated is use to handle the termination of a background process. It is not written here.

int runcmd(char *cmd)
{
  char* argv[MAX_ARGS];
  pid_t child_pid;
  int child_status;

  parsecmd(cmd,argv);
  child_pid = fork();
  if(child_pid == 0) {
    /* This is done by the child process. */

    execvp(argv[0], argv);

    /* If execvp returns, it must have failed. */

    fprintf( stderr, "execvp failed due to %s\n", strerror(errno) );
    exit(0);
  }
  else {
     /* This is run by the parent.  Wait for the child
        to terminate. */

     do {
       pid_t tpid = wait(&child_status);
       if(tpid != child_pid) process_terminated(tpid);
     } while(tpid != child_pid);

     return child_status;
  }
}
```